# Odoo 10 - Sale Order Email Template

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have created a custom sale order report and that report shall be used when user clicks on "Send by Email".

I have check the mail template but I can not find where the specific attachment to be used is specified.

How could I select a different sale order report template?

```
<p>Dear ${object.partner_id.name}
% set access_action = object.with_context(force_website=True).get_access_action()
% set doc_name = 'quotation' if object.state in ('draft', 'sent') else 'order confirmation'
% set is_online = access_action and access_action['type'] == 'ir.actions.act_url'
% set access_name = is_online and object.template_id and doc_name == 'quotation' and 'Accept and pay %s online' % doc_name or 'View %s' % doc_name
% set access_url = is_online and access_action['url'] or None

% if object.partner_id.parent_id:
    (<i>${object.partner_id.parent_id.name}</i>)
% endif
,</p>
<p>
Here is your ${doc_name} <strong>${object.name}</strong>
% if object.origin:
(with reference: ${object.origin} )
% endif
amounting in <strong>${object.amount_total}
${object.pricelist_id.currency_id.name}</strong>
from ${object.company_id.name}.
</p>

    <br><br>
% if is_online:
    <center>
        <a href="${access_url}" style="background-color: #1abc9c; padding: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: #fff; border-radius: 5px; font-size: 16px;"  class="o_default_snippet_text">${access_name}</a>
        <br><br>
        <span style="color:#888888">(or view attached PDF)</span>
    </center>
    <br>
% endif

<p>You can reply to this email if you have any questions.</p>
<p>Thank you,</p>

<p style="color:#eeeeee;">
% if object.user_id and object.user_id.signature:
    ${object.user_id.signature | safe}
% endif
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the report template by mail.template model with the attribute

```
<field name="report_template" ref="modulename.report_name"/>
```

eg:

```
    <record id="email_template_edi_invoice" model="mail.template">
        <field name="name">Invoice - Send by Email (Portal)</field>
        <field name="email_from">${(object.user_id.email and '%s &lt;%s&gt;' % (object.user_id.name, object.user_id.email) or '')|safe}</field>
        <field name="subject">${object.company_id.name} Invoice (Ref ${object.number or 'n/a' })</field>
        <field name="partner_to">${object.partner_id.id}</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="account.model_account_invoice"/>
        <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
        <field name="report_template" ref="account.account_invoices"/>
        <field name="report_name">Invoice_${(object.number or '').replace('/','_')}_${object.state == 'draft' and 'draft' or ''}</field>
        <field name="lang">${object.partner_id.lang}</field>
        <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[
<div style="font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Ubuntu, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); ">

    <p>Hello ${object.partner_id.name},</p>

    <p>A new invoice is available for you: </p>

    <p style="border-left: 1px solid #8e0000; margin-left: 30px;">
       &nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>REFERENCES</strong><br />
       &nbsp;&nbsp;Invoice number: <strong>${object.number}</strong><br />
       &nbsp;&nbsp;Invoice total: <strong>${object.amount_total} ${object.currency_id.name}</strong><br />
       &nbsp;&nbsp;Invoice date: ${object.date_invoice}<br />
       % if object.origin:
       &nbsp;&nbsp;Order reference: ${object.origin}<br />
       % endif
       % if object.user_id:
       &nbsp;&nbsp;Your contact: <a href="mailto:${object.user_id.email or ''}?subject=Invoice%20${object.number}">${object.user_id.name}</a>
       % endif
    </p>  

    % set signup_url = object.get_signup_url()
    % if signup_url:
    <p>
    You can access the invoice document and pay online via our Customer Portal:
    </p>
        <a style="display:block; width: 150px; height:20px; margin-left: 120px; color: #DDD; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; text-decoration: none !important; line-height: 1; padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px; background-color: #8E0000; border-radius: 5px 5px; background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;"
           href="${signup_url}">View Invoice</a>
    % endif

    % if object.paypal_url:
    <br/>
    <p>It is also possible to directly pay with Paypal:</p>
        <a style="margin-left: 120px;" href="${object.paypal_url}">
            <img class="oe_edi_paypal_button" src="/sale/static/img/btn_paynowcc_lg.gif"/>
        </a>
    % endif

    <br/>
    <p>If you have any question, do not hesitate to contact us.</p>
    <p>Thank you for choosing ${object.company_id.name or 'us'}!</p>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div style="width: 375px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #8E0000; border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px; background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;">
        <h3 style="margin: 0px; padding: 2px 14px; font-size: 12px; color: #DDD;">
            <strong style="text-transform:uppercase;">${object.company_id.name}</strong></h3>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 347px; margin: 0px; padding: 5px 14px; line-height: 16px; background-color: #F2F2F2;">
        <span style="color: #222; margin-bottom: 5px; display: block; ">
            ${object.company_id.partner_id.sudo().with_context(show_address=True, html_format=True).name_get()[0][1] | safe}
        </span>
        % if object.company_id.phone:
            <div style="margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; ">
                Phone:&nbsp; ${object.company_id.phone}
            </div>
        % endif
        % if object.company_id.website:
            <div>
                Web :&nbsp;<a href="${object.company_id.website}">${object.company_id.website}</a>
            </div>
        % endif
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
        ]]></field>
    </record>
```